# Why does cURL think I am downloading something?

Tags: 18.04, curl

Here is what my curl command looks like:

```
curl -d "$(curl localhost:8080/fetchStrs)" localhost:8080/uppercase,toChars -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I expected to get back:

```
["T","E","S","T","1","T","E","S","T","2"]
```

But instead I got this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    17  100    17    0     0   5666      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5666
["T","E","S","T","1","T","E","S","T","2"]
```

Why does curl think that I am downloading something? How to remove the download metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, it was an easy fix:

```
curl -d "$(curl -s localhost:8080/fetchStrs)" localhost:8080/uppercase,toChars -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

`-s` will do it silently.

Comment: But I am still curious about why curl thaught that I am downloading something at first place while it doesn't show any progress bar when the commands are executed separately.